# Error editing connection - Did not find a connection with UUID

Tags: settings, system, networking, elementary-project, ethernet

Last 3 months i continuously using the elementary OS (elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera - with dual boot) for personal use. This is my first linux OS of my PC, and I am not using a linux version like before. I am facing alot of OS stability issues in this time. One the main issue on detecting the network adapeters.
I have two network interfaces, one wired LAN and another is wireless adapter. I have a strange issue when i try to enable the wired lan i got a message like below message.

[image]

I already googled many hours and find out some instructions for editing the network configuration and restart the network manager service many times. but no use. I am really disappointed about the stability of elementary os. Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and type
sudo nmtui. You should be able to manage networks there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable replay, but how can i recreate the lan network card.

Comment: If you will type sudo nmtui there will be an option to add a network. You can choose between wireless or LAN network there. You can set the dynamic or static IP address etc. If you need more help, let me know. I can try to help. Question is does your PC detects the network card, I mean hardware. What sudo lscpi command shows? Can you paste results to pastebin and provide a link?

Comment: Thank you very much for your great support.